# .htaccess - Redirect subdomain to main domain (only if NOT xyz.php)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, conditional-statements

Hi I would like to redirect the following sobdomain:

**subdomain.domain.com** to **domain.com**

ONLY if the address/script is NOT subdomain.domain.com/xyz.php

some examples:

subdomain.domain.com/index.php -> 301 redirect to domain.com/index.php

subdomain.domain.com/123.php -> 301 redirect to domain.com/123.php

subdomain.domain.com/xyz.php (no redirect)

I tried to redirect with the following code but I'm struggling with the condition. The redirect itself works... however for all pages:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.co.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteRule !^subdomain.domain.co.uk/xyz.php$ domain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so what, show us...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution which works. if someone struggles with the same issue you can try this .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^xyz\.php($|/) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

The first line addresses the subdomain (case insensitive)
The second line redirects all sites Except the specified xyz.php to the main domain (301)